# How can I improve the efficiency of an ng-repeat that includes a filter and a reorder?

Tags: angularjs

I have a grid on my page that is populated like this:

```
   <tr data-ng-repeat="row in grid.view  = (grid.data | filter:isProblemInRange | orderBy:option.problemOrderBy[option.sProblemOrderBy].key:option.sProblemSortDirection) track by row.problemId">
```

The grid can have up to 500 rows. Once the data is retrieved it's possible for a user to filter the rows which is where the isProblemInRange filter is used. It's also possible for the user to reorder the rows. As can be expected this all takes time.

Is there anything that I could do to make this more efficient?

Could I take all of this code out of my ng-repeat and put in the part that creates the grid.view in my controller?

Note that the isProblemInRange is dynamic. As a user types into a select box then after debouncing the numbers entered are used in the filter to restrict the rows that appear on the screen.

One more thing. The data in the grid changes only when the user clicks on a row and it opens a modal. After a user clicks save on the modal then one single row of the grid.data is changed. Is there something I could do to stop ng-repeat from watching every field on every row and have it just respond after my modal has done a save which is the only time the grid data numbers change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every filter is callable fom JavaScript code directly. See http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:filter for an example of the usage of the "filter" filter.

So you could indeed call these filters directly from your controller each time the data or the user-defined order and criteria change, which would avoid the unnecessary watches.

```
var filteredData = $filter('filter')($scope.grid.data, $scope.isProblemInRange);
var orderedFilteredData = $filter('orderBy')(filteredData, 
                      $scope.option.problemOrderBy[option.sProblemOrderBy].key, 
                      $scope.option.sProblemSortDirection);
$scope.orderedFilteredData = orderedFilteredData;
```

And then in your view, you just need to iterate on the already filtered and ordered data:

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="row in orderedFilteredData">
```

Comment: If you don't mind. Could you give a very short example of how I could do this for the ng-repeat that I have. Would I still need to create "row in grid.view  = (grid.data" in my ng-repeat ? The same goes for the user ordering. How could I do that inside the controller?